# background image of page in IONIC 2

Tags: image, sass, ionic2

I'm trying  to   set a  background  image  for  a  page  in IONIC 2.
I have tried multiple  things.

```
my Html  code**strong text**

<ion-content  class="myview"   padding class="letsstart">

</ion-content>

**my scss**

.myview {


    background-image: url('../../img/letsstart.jpg');
// background-image: url('/img/letsstart.jpg');
// background-image: url('img/letsstart.jpg');
// background-image: url('../img/letsstart.jpg');
// background-image: url('./img/letsstart.jpg');

}
```

Above  mentioned ways  are  not  working.. 
is something  I am  missing ??

Answer (score 1):

Try including a variable in ts with your url as value and then use the variable in html.

TS

```
 constructor(){
     this.backimg = 'img/letsstart.jpg';
    }
```

HTML

> ```
> <ion-content class="login-content" style="background-image: url('{{backimg}}')">
> </ion-content>
> ```

SCSS

```
.login-content{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

It worked for me. Hope this helps you too.

Comment: Have  u  implemented setting  direct path ?

Comment: I'm following  same  path.  Is  it rendering  perfectly  for  u ?

Comment: Inline  styling  is  working  for  me...  INTERNAL AND  EXTERNAL  STYLING  not  working.

Comment: have you included you external styling file location in app.core.scss?

Comment: By class name  in CSS  its  not  rendering..By ID , its  working..  whether  its  working  for  u  by  class name

Comment: @Aish123 , add the css file , eg. [at]import "../pages/getting-started/getting-started"; into subfolder theme/app.core.scss and app.core.scss in the root folder

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `background-image`:

```
 background-image: url('../../img/letsstart.jpg');
```

Use `background`:

```
 background: url('../../img/letsstart.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it work use the following format. This should work for both web and the device.

```
 background-image: url('../img/lola_akinmade_akerstrom-white_reindeer-1605.jpg');
```

Credit:
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/css-body-background-image-not-showing/9649/6

Answer (score 0):

**Ionic 3.10.1**

Include without quotes and the finish into declaration

```
page-login {
    .login-background{
        background: no-repeat fixed center; 
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        background-image: url(/assets/img/background.jpg);
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Ionic 3 result]

[Photo by Samuel Fyfe on Unsplash](https://unsplash.com/search/photos/people?modal=%7B%22type%22%3A%22credit-badge%22%2C%22userId%22%3A%22MYsDWGA1FYg%22%7D&photo=jhjSV7awY3Y)

Answer (score 0):

Anywhere you are, on any level, keep using the path `../assets/your_folder/your-image.*`

```css
ion-content {
   background: url("../assets/images/city-view_min_resized.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
   height: 100%;
}
```

Hope it helps :)